# How to debug javascript file while running Flask project in VSCode?

Tags: javascript, python, debugging, flask, visual-studio-code

I want to debug my "app.js" file while running my Flask application but I'm not sure how to do so. I've tried running my application through the debugger using the Python Flask configuration but I still can't use any of the debugging tools in my app.js file.

I also can't view any of my console.log statements from app.js. I always run the below statement to start my Flask application.

```
FLASK_ENV=development flask run
```

Any guidance would be appreciated